# How to use atoi in kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Unable to `#include <stdlib.h>`, now I need to write my own `int my_atoi(char* str)` function in my kernel module. But I think that there must be more simple ways to use this function and some others from stdlib (atof, itoa, etc.). Do you know something about that?

Comment: There are many "standard C" functions already available in the kernel. Have you tried to search for an `atoi` like function?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert from `char*` to `int` without `atoi` in the following way,

```
#include "ctype.h"

int charToInt(const char *s)
{
  int n;
  unsigned char sign = 0;

  while (isspace(*s))
  {
    s++;
  }

  if (*s == '-')
  {
    sign = 1;
    s++;
  }
  else if (*s == '+')
  {
    s++;
  }

  n=0;

  while (isdigit(*s))
  {
    n = n * 10 + *s++ - '0';
  }

  return sign ? -n : n;
}


int main (){

    const char * g = "123456";

    printf("num:%d",charToInt(g));
    return 0;
}
```

which produces the output,

> 123456

Comment: Your solution prints the representation of an 'int' but does not in itself provide an 'int' value, as does 'atoi'.

Comment: @GuntherSchulz, Enlighten me! `(・・?` but as far as I know (and I don't really know that much), `atoi()` returns an `int` value. And at least [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) it says for `atoi()`, *"**Return value:** Integer value corresponding to the contents of str on success."*

Comment: where does your code return an `int` with ***value*** 123456? i.e. can your code be used to assign a value, e.g. 'int Value = JoeysCode("123456");`.

Comment: No, it cannot. For that you'd have to `sum += x * (int)pow(10, n-i-1)` or so, to put back the individually extracted `int`s into a single number.

Comment: Did that comment help @GuntherSchulz? Or should I edit my answer with the complete code?

Comment: You _really_ should edit your answer, lest you lead some people astray.. Be mindful of OPs desire to *NOT* roll out his own `atoi` (which im dead sure he could have done)

Comment: *"Be mindful of OPs desire to NOT roll out his own atoi"*, in that case he really has then the answers in the duplicate question to look at and use `kstrtol`.

Comment: Upvote given for edit, and yes dupe is the answer he probably wanted

Comment: you know `atio` also handles leading whitespaces, leading `+` and leading `-` right?

Comment: @GuntherSchulz, I didn't know that. Thanks for the edit.